# Updating a column giving error in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

I am trying to update a column named 'is_shared' in laravel but it is giving error.

I tried.

```
public static function setShared($key, $status = true){
    $input = ScorecardInputMeta::where("key", $key)->first();
    if($input){
       $input->is_shared = $status;
       $input->save;
    }
}//end function
```

> Error:
>   {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Call
>   to a member function getResults() on
>   boolean","file":"D:\Projects\hbi_private\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php","line":2070}}

Comment: You forgot the most important part... the actual error!

Comment: @user3621494 I have written the errors messages now

Comment: You should check for `$status` not being `null` or being something else than what you expct (when there's no result from your query IIRC), before assuming it's an object. Also, is ScorecardInputMeta a proper eloquent model?

Comment: Check `$input` for `null` or use `firstOrFail`

Comment: please use dd($input) for check what return in $input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ScorecardInputMeta` is an `Eloquent Model`, try:

```
public static function setShared($key, $status = true)
{
    // ->where(column, operator, value)
    $input = ScorecardInputMeta::where('key', '=', $key)->first();

    // check if input is not null or an object
    if ($input) {
        $input->is_shared = $status;
        $input->save(); // changed from $input->save
    }
}
```

Comment: $input->save gives the error, everything else is working fine

Comment: $input->save(); line is giving the error everything else is working fine

Comment: Can you show the entire `ScorecardInputMeta` class?